# How to deal with the .next() function with hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a custom drop down menu with arrow key functions as well as being filtered by `:contains`.

I can't seem to get past the following code. What is happening is that I need to start the selection at the current hovered li, then proceed to the next or previous li that has the class `match`.

My following code starts correctly but even though it has `.next('.match')` it wont pass the `<li>`'s that either don't have the class (`match`) or are (hidden)

Does the `next()` function break on hidden elements?

Jquery Code

```
 $('.dropdown_shell.opened li.match.hovered')
     .next('.match')
     .addClass('hovered')
     .siblings()
     .removeClass('hovered');
```

Html

```
<ul class="scroll">
     <li class="selected default match">None</li>
     <li class="" style="display: none;">For Sale</li>
     <li class="match">For Rent</li>
     <li class="" style="display: none;">For Lease</li>
     <li class="match hovered">Sale or Lease</li>
     <li class="match">New Listing</li>
     <li class="match">Open House</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `next()` function is not doing what you think it is. It looks at the next element, and *only* matches it if it makes the given selector. Otherwise it returns  an empty jQuery object.

Instead, you want [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll), which looks at all future siblings, then use the `first()` method (or `:first`) selector to match the first one.

You can see this working here; http://jsfiddle.net/DH3hG/

To answer your question about whether `next()` considers hidden elements; *yes* it does. Anything that is inserted into the DOM is considered.

Comment: Ok, this is great! Many thanks man...just for clarification, I was under the impression that .next('selector') was legit...does it actually do anything or is it the same as .next() ?

Comment: @VIDesignz: `next()` will always select the immediate sibling and return it. `next(selector)` will only select the immediate sibling if it matches the given selector... otherwise an empty object is returned.

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now... .next() is only the next element no matter what, then the (selector) is a filter for that one only... I appreciate the help!!